# What details does the Bible have about Jesus' birth and childhood?

Tags: gospels, historical-jesus

What details does the Bible have about Jesus' birth and childhood?

The Quran has a story where Jesus miraculously spoke from the cradle:

> O sister of Aaron, your father was not a man of evil, nor was your
>   mother unchaste."
>
> So she pointed to him. They said, "How can we speak to one who is in
>   the cradle a child?"
>
> [Jesus] said, "Indeed, I am the servant of Allah . He has given me the
>   Scripture and made me a prophet.
>
> And He has made me blessed wherever I am and has enjoined upon me
>   prayer and zakah as long as I remain alive
>
> And [made me] dutiful to my mother, and He has not made me a wretched
>   tyrant.
>
> And peace is on me the day I was born and the day I will die and the
>   day I am raised alive."
>
> That is Jesus, the son of Mary - the word of truth about which they
>   are in dispute.
>
> http://quran.com/19 verse 30 onwards

Is this story in the Bible?

Is there a specific section in the Bible that focuses on Jesus' childhood?

Comment: Simply stated There is nothing in the Bible that even remotely resembles, Jesus speaking as a baby.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an assertion, not explainable by any Biblical Scriptures, and any answer given would have to be opinion.

Comment: So there are zero references of what happened during the early childhood period you mean? I didn't know that.

Comment: That is not what I said! There are references to such things as the family going to Egypt, and such, but any reference to Jesus performing any miracles as a child simply do not exist, every indication we have in the Bible shows Jesus as an average type baby. The first miracle of Jesus as far as the Bible goes is him turning water into wine. Every miracle Jesus performed was clearly meant to show the power of God.

Comment: Except for a short story about Christ when he was about 12, which does not involve miracles, there is practically nothing about his youth in the Bible.

Comment: @Cecil The question clearly asks if this story from the Quran is also in the Bible. Straight forward question, which I answered above. No opinion necessary.

Comment: @fredsbend The opinion part comes in where he asks for The people's and Mary's reaction to Jesus speaking as a baby, unless I have misread it.

Comment: @Cecil I think he has assumed that the Bible contains the same story, therefore, perhaps more details. This led to poor wording.

Comment: @fredsbend I asked that if was any references to his early life when he was a young child, and how people reacted to him being born w/o a father.  What deference was used?  People must have slandered her and the child like in the Jewish scriptures.

Comment: @user1361315 That is a different question than your original implies. Yes, there is a hint that Jesus and Mary were looked down upon. There is also a hint that Joseph died early in Jesus' life, so that may have been the reason. He is called the "son of Mary" in [Mark 6:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+6), rather than the "son of Joseph." But Jesus was an adult when this happened; about 30 years old. Until his death, Joseph treated Jesus as his own. Only a few would actually know Joseph was not his father.

Comment: This is interesting as I thought Islam taught that Jesus did not die, but this verse clearly indicates that He did.

Comment: @Narnian "and the day I will die "  Islam teaches he will return to complete his life/mission.

Answer (score 17):

The life of Jesus is recorded separately in four different books of the Bible.  These four books are collectively called [*The Gospels*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gospels).  Some of them record details of Jesus early life and some do not:

- [**Matthew**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%201&version=NASB) - Records His birth and then a visit from the wise men before fleeing from Herod to Egypt.  The book then skips to His baptism as an adult.
- [**Mark**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%201&version=NASB) - Contains no information about His childhood.
- [**Luke**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201&version=NASB) - Records His birth and circumcision.  The book then skips to an incident when He was twelve years old and visited the temple.  It then jumps to his baptism as an adult.
- [**John**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201&version=NASB) - Contains no information about His childhood.

The closest thing that the Bible comes to describing the rest of Jesus' early life is the following verse:

[Luke 2:40 (NASB)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202:40&version=NASB)

> The Child continued to grow and become strong, increasing in wisdom; and the grace of God was upon Him.

As you can see, none of the Gospels describe the incident that you quoted from the Quran, nor any of the circumstances surrounding it.  I am unaware of any mainstream Christians who would consider that story in the Quran to be an accurate account.

Although the Bible doesn't address Jesus' childhood in detail, it does describe a time when Jesus, during His public ministry as an adult, visited His home town of Nazareth.  The events that happened there may indirectly shed some light on His childhood:

[Matthew 13:53-58 (NASB)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2013%3A53-58&version=NASB)

> When Jesus had finished these parables, He departed from there. He came to His hometown and began teaching them in their synagogue, so that they were astonished, and said, “Where did this man get this wisdom and these miraculous powers? Is not this the carpenter’s son? Is not His mother called Mary, and His brothers, James and Joseph and Simon and Judas? And His sisters, are they not all with us? Where then did this man get all these things?” And they took offense at Him. But Jesus said to them, “A prophet is not without honor except in his hometown and in his own household.” And He did not do many miracles there because of their unbelief.

Also, see [Mark 6:1-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206%3A1-6&version=NASB) for a parallel account.  Although that passage does not specifically say so, it does seem to imply that Jesus did not regularly perform miracles during his childhood.

Answer (score -2):

There are signs and miracles that were not recorded in the Bible, and this happens to be one of them. Qur'an is explicit on the miracles and signs performed by Jesus the son of Mary (peace and blessings of God be upon him).

Comment: While it's true that the Biblical accounts are not exhaustive, the OP was asking if there was any *Biblical* text that might support the aforementioned story. The answer is a resounding "*no*". Christians, pretty much by definition, do not accept the Qur'an (else they would be Islamic, not Christian).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: This does not answer the question. Down-voted -1.

Comment: The question asks for details from the Bible.